# Is file_exists() compatible with timthumb.php?

Tags: loop, timthumb

I'm using the latest timthumb script to generate my post thumbnails and include them along with the excerpt. Though I only want the thumbnails to load if their files actually exist, otherwise I don't even want the image placeholder to load.

I'm going to be using this on a multi-user network, which is still in the early stages of development. And I want to test if the posts author has neglected to properly add the "thumb" custom field, which if they have, would normally return a 404 not found error.

So I've put the following code in my loop which first determines if the post has any images then using the file path for the first image listed in the post checks if the file exists.

```
<?php
$content = $post->post_content;
$searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';
preg_match_all($searchimages, $content, $pics);
$iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);
if($iNumberOfPics > 0){
    $blogTemplate = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $imgSrc = get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true);
    $imgSrc = $blogTemplate . "/scripts/timthumb.php?src=" . $imgSrc . "&w=300&zc=1";

    if(file_exists($imgSrc)){ ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imgSrc; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a><?php              
    }
}
?>
```

I've tested the $imgSrc string that's outputted which is valid, it is an existing file though the my file_exists($imgSrc) function always returns false. I'm left wondering if the timthumb script is compatible with the file_exists() function?

Comment: `file_exists()` is a PHP function. TimThumb is an independent, third-party script that is unrelated to WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_exists(); and is_readable(); (which I've decided to go for instead as it detects if the file is readable as well as if it exists) both require the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; variable to be called as the file is physically stored on the file server's HDD and therefore replaces the need to declare the domain name in the function. Do it like this:

```
is_readable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?+(example\.com)\/?/','',$imgSrc);
```

no need to write any special apache code.

Answer (score 1):

The file_exists() function is a built in php function and should work everywhere. But with the way you're doing it, is wrong. You cannot use a query string within a php file to check if the file exists. Just because its a valid link, doesn't mean the file_exists(). There is no file on your server by the name of /scripts/timthumb.php?src=*****

You need to do the following to your code:

```
<?php
$content = $post->post_content;
$searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';
preg_match_all($searchimages, $content, $pics);
$iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);
if($iNumberOfPics > 0){
    $blogTemplate = get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    $imgSrc = get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true);

    if(file_exists($imgSrc)){ 
    $imgSrc = $blogTemplate . "/scripts/timthumb.php?src=" . $imgSrc . "&w=300&zc=1";
    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="thumb" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imgSrc; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a><?php              
    }
}
?>
```

This way you're actually checking for the real file name and then changing the url to the query string url later, after you know the file exists.

Comment: I've already tried removing the 2nd definition of $imgSrc altogether (the one with "scripts/timthumb.php?src=") but it still returns false. I've also echoed the $imgSrc string after I did that which the right file path.I've already tried removing the 2nd definition of $imgSrc altogether (the one with "scripts/timthumb.php?src=") but it still returns false. I've also echoed the $imgSrc string after I did that which returned the right file path.

Comment: My mistake, file_exists should be using the local path not the url to the image.  I wouldn't even check if the file_exists and I would just echo it out if the user has to have a post_meta set in order for the image source to even be available.  It should be on the user to be sure the file is valid.

You can either do that, or you can use the following http://pastebin.com/VpHK0kLb to check the http response you get from that URL.  If you get a 400 code back, you're good.

Comment: Ok, bare with me while I implement your second suggestion as that'll come in very handy for something else I'm working on as well as this topic and if it works you'll get a very honourable mention :-)

Comment: Sorry @Kevin it didn't work - "Fatal error: Call to undefined function pcntl_fork() ...... on line 24". I would really like that function to work though as it'd be amazingly useful for me.

Comment: For that function to work you have to install the module for it.  Do you have root access to your server?

Comment: Hmmm, no at the moment it's only running on shared hosting and if I did have root level access I wouldn't have a clue what to do so I'll ask my host to help with that. Cheers!

Comment: Apparently it's not at all possible on shared hosting though I'll definitely keep this in mind for if and when I switch to non-shared hosting. Sorry I can't confirm it's the right answer or not as I obviously can't test it. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: I'm about to leave work, I'll rewrite that function for you later tonight without using that apache module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1748/discussion-between-ben-and-kevin-langley-jr)